# Is becoming a member of a network marketing business halal?

Tags: halal-haram, work

I want to be a member of a network marketing company which deals in food supplement. According to the company the more members you bring to the company the more your commission you get. Please is it halal for a Muslim to be a member?

Comment: there is nothing haram in it.

Comment: Well plz go though [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16867/11938) it sounds good to me...

Comment: i dont think so it will be haram, but i also waiting for any good response

Comment: Aside from the fact that its not haram (nor is this question related at all to the study of Islam), you may want to be careful about this company. It sounds like a Ponzi/pyramid scheme to me. Are they asking you to pay a large amount of money upfront?

Answer (score 1):

Assalamualaikum,

According to majority of the scholars this is impermissible. Every business and its dealings are different. We should consult a scholar on exactly what the business is and in this very case food supplement, if it is halal or haram, and how the profits are shared among members.

The problem comes in when you sit idle do nothing and make money. And most of the networking and pyramid schemes are fraud or have some strings attached which are not very clear to normal people. It sometimes is accounted as gambling as a person doesn't know if its a profit or loss without real hard work. Also is the product not adultered? Would you recommend it to your family. These are some ethical questions but do factor in.

Not stepping on any ones toes. Just explaining from what I've learned. Consulting a scholar with specifics is the best option. And Allah knows best...

Comment: Yes,, especially the multi level marketing that sounds injustice to me,,,
The one with more contacts earns more, and the one with less works hard...!!!