# Is investment in the cryptocurrency OneCoin OneLife halal?

Tags: halal-haram, money, investment

There is a new cryptocurrency launched with some profit scheme named [OneCoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneCoin) OneLife. Can you please give your guidance either investment in OneLife scheme is halal or haram?

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. We are not a typical an internet forum. I strongly recommend you to take our 2 min. [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about this site and the stack exchange model. We need more details in order to answer this question. Why do you think it wouldn't be halal?

Comment: About Ponzi schemes: There is an answer about there [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/16867/15201) - the conclusion in the answer is: *"Ponzi schemes are haraam since they are the commercial equivalents of perpetual motion machines, and they work on the assumption of unending returns."*

Answer (score 2):

For an in-depth Research Paper covering the Onecoin ponzi scam and massive criminal fraud, written by Muslim scholars, please see:
https://nawadir.org/2016/12/01/is-onecoin-permissible/.  From this fatwa:

> The OneCoin scheme contains fraud and deception leading to unlawful  consumption of wealth which is impermissible.
>
> Approved and endorsed by Mufti Amjad Mohammed, Mufti Faisal Niazi al-Mahmudi, Shaykh Yusuf Shabbir