# How can I escape from a haraam multilevel network marketing scheme?

Tags: practical-islam, business

I'm a 20 year old Muslim boy, residing in India, and recently I came across these associates of multilevel network marketing who promised me wealth, fortune and fulfillment of all my lavish dreams. If I too join as an associate under them and recruit others to join under me. They provoked greed in me and I joined their company only to find later that multilevel network marketing is haraam in Islam.

I've already paid my joining fee which was INR 11,000 but have not yet promoted the product. As soon as I learned that it is haraam, I tried to pull myself out of it.

What should I do in my current position as I have already unintentionally invested in haraam business?

Should I bear my loss and forget about it or should I incur it through commission and quit when I'm reimbursed of the fee I've paid?

Comment: See also: ["What is Shariah View on Multi Level Marketing/Network Marketing?"](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/805/9123) and [others](http://islam.stackexchange.com/search?q=network+marketing)

Comment: Multi Level Marketing? This is known as a Pyramid scheme and is an unsustainable business model and its borderline scamming. Stay away from these as you are likely to lose a significant about of money. Interestingly enough, I came across this infographic: http://i.imgur.com/EdrEE97.png

Comment: Whoever told you that it is haraam???

Comment: Check out this answer: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/16812/is-mlm-business-with-a-binary-plan-halal/16867#16867

Answer (score 1):

وَإِن تُبْتُمْ فَلَكُمْ رُءُوسُ أَمْوَٰلِكُمْ لَا تَظْلِمُونَ وَلَا تُظْلَمُونَ 

this is the Ayat in surat al baqara : 279. It came in the discussion of Interest (Which is haram as well).

It says that "But if you repent, you may have your principal(Investment) - [thus] you do no wrong, nor are you wronged."

Based on this Ayat, You can get your investment back and stop it. No more profit from the deals.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-level network marketing is no different from any other business. All businesses have good and bad people and unfortunately MLM seems to have more bad than good.

Having said that, there are still lots of good honest MLM businesses about. You just need to find them.

I have never paid the sorts of money you have.

You must tread carefully and research the business for yourself and not listen to the hype that other people feed you.

Answer (score -2):

My personal opinion is to let go of the amount ...because I did the same too ...and unfortunately I had to incur a greater loss of something close to 40k (Nd I was just 19 then).

The reason why I say this is because if u are promoting it further onn to our other young brothers they may get fantasised by this and start practicing it and go onn to include many or all of those that they come across unknowingly and unintentionally all of them ending up doing haraam and making haraam earnings ...some may even tend to make it their principal source of earnings .
And who will b the one core person responsible for all this ...YOUU ...YOUU WILL HAVE BECOME THE SPARK AND INITIATION TO ALL THEIR WRATH . So please realise at this point what it can create n lead to n STOPPPPP for the sake of Allah ....n surely Allah will give u more through other means ...he is the rabbul aalameen  jazakallahu khaira !!

Answer (score -3):

The prophet (p.b.u.h) said......work is ibaada.....how can it be halaal if you have not worked for it......introducing members does not mean you worked.....what do you sell to get a profit.....rejestering as a member once and you receive more than you gave.....is that not ribaa? I don't think such a business is right for a muslim....but am not judging anything....or anyone....Allah knows best

Comment: Your opinion doesn't represent an answer unless you can support it by evidences. We don't look for opinion based answers rather than focus answers on the actual questions (see [answer]).